# What is 'could be in for a rocket'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a [blog](http://www.news.com.au/travel/world-travel/asia/kim-jong-uns-efforts-to-attract-tourists-to-north-korea-hit-by-terrible-tripadvisor-reviews/news-story/d98577a8c393f0d3041dabb2f403d571), I could not understand the meaning of 'could be in for a rocket'.

> TRAVELLERS have voted a dingy resort the worst hotel in Kim Jong-un’s showpiece capital Pyongyang — and the manager ***could be in for a rocket***.

Is it an idiomatic expression? Does it mean that the manager is not available to respond? Or, looking at the Premier's impression, does it mean that now the manager would get a capital punishment?

Comment: Idiom for severe verbal criticism, sufficient to induce an idle person to begin working very hard.

Comment: [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rocket) [IN SINGULAR] British informal **A severe reprimand.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Be in for*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in?q=to+be+in+for#in__29) is a phrasal verb meaning "have good reason to expect something", typically something unpleasant, here - as it was said in the comments - *a severe reprimand* which is one of the meanings of the noun [*rocket*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rocket) (Brittish informal usage).